# What has scholarly research found about variations in live performances of the same songs by the same artists?

Tags: musicology, live, books

I am interested in the degree with which performances of the same songs by the same artists differ. In this regard, I wonder what scholarly research has found about such variations, and I especially appreciate well-referenced answers.

The underlying motivation is that I consider creating a (supervised) machine learning algorithm that detects what kinds of variations of existing songs are pleasing to audiences, and applies such variations so as to "liveify" recorded songs, which hopefully makes listening experiences more varied and enjoyable to some people.

Comment: Welcome! Questions along the lines of "point me toward resources" are off-topic here, because the answers easily become low-value lists of dad links. This question could be made on-topic fairly easily by simply asking about the *content* you're looking for, something like "What has scholarly research found about variations in live performance? I'd especially appreciate well-referenced answers." BUT...

Comment: 1) I very much doubt such research exists. It would have to contend both with extreme variation (an artist rendering a given song either as a slow ballad or a speed-punk number from one tour or show to the next) and minor variation (holding a fermata a second longer one day, perhaps even unconsciously). Any such research would be most likely observational, narrow sociological case studies (e.g. "here's how this one artist varied over the year I spent with them") and not a large body of data. And...

Comment: 2) it's hard to answer this question without getting sidetracked into critique of the planned app. Stack Exchange isn't a discussion board, but feel free to bring it up in the chat room. Personally, I think there's a fundamental flaw: Much of what makes live experiences memorable doesn't lie only in the notes that are played. It's about eye contact, audience interaction, shared awareness among the audience, etc. That's why you can have "that one show you'll remember forever," but we seldom feel that way about even a well-captured live album.

Comment: 'applies such variations so as to "liveify" recorded songs, which hopefully makes listening experiences more varied and enjoyable.' Errr... huh? Meaning the live versions are generally considered better by listeners? I'm not like that. I almost always prefer the studio version.

Comment: @AndyBonner Thank you for your explanations. I've edited the question. Does it adhere to Music SE's policies now? And: should I remove the part about the machine learning algorithm?

Comment: @ToddWilcox You may, of course, disagree with my views. The idea, though, is not so much as adjust songs to make they seem like they've been played live. It's about using different live performances to discover what kinds of variations to studio recordings the artists deemed appropriate, and use those variations to generate different versions of the same song, so as to make the listening experience more varied to those who'd like such an experience.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to edit this question to not be either a resource request or too broad. You want someone else to do a lot of research for you on a topic. That is different from asking for an objective answer to a question that can be provided in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @ToddWilcox This type of question is considered perfectly normal on other SE venues, including mathoverflow and math stack exchange. My aim is not to make other people do a lot of research for me. It's about requesting information from experts who are much more knowledgeable on this topic than myself, which could help me get started in this field more quickly.

Comment: Thanks; in my opinion it's fine now; asking "tell me what there is to know, with references please" rather than just "point me toward references." It could benefit by explaining more about what kind of "differences" you have in mind; this could also help narrow an otherwise very broad topic. I'd keep the bit about the AI goal, since it explains where you're coming from, and hopefully people can discipline themselves not to be distracted by it :D. I still doubt that such research exists (or could, by definition), but good luck!